# How to extract the quadratic fit from stat_smooth when using a transformed axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I am trying to extract the line for my quadratic fit so that I can work out the x coordinate at y = 0.1 but the lm() and the stat_smooth are giving me different fits because of the log transformation on my y axis.

Minimum dataset:

```r
> xvals <- c(0,1,2,2.5,3,5,7.5,10)
> yvals <- c(1,0.65,0.425,0.45,0.26,0.085,0.0121667,0.000675)
> df <- cbind.dataframe(xvals,yvals)
> 
> ggplot(df, aes(x = xvals, y = yvals))+
> stat_smooth(method= 'lm', formula = y~poly(x,2), se = F, color = 'blue')+
> stat_function(fun=function(x) 0.93389 + -0.25608 *x + 0.01663*x^2, color = 'green')+
> geom_point(color = 'blue', shape = 22, size = 3)+
> geom_hline(yintercept = 0.1)+
> geom_vline(xintercept = 4.675868)+
> scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10')
```

[image]

The stat_function coordinates are derived from an lm (I have also done poly(x,2) raw = T and it gives the same coordinates.

```r
> lm(df, formula = yvals ~ I(xvals^2) + I(xvals))
```

and I have drawn the black lines by solving the equation so when y = 0.1 the lm gives me that x = 4.7. However as you can see this does not line up with the stat_smooth line because the equation is slightly differnet.

If I take the log transformation off the y axis, the lines are drawn on top of each other and the stat_smooth line crosses at 4.7.

My understanding from some searching is that this is caused by ggplot transforming the data before it does the polynomial fit unless I've just made a huge blunder in which case any help is welcomed.

Does anyone know how I can either transform the data I put into my lm or derive the equation stat_smooth is using to get the coordinates where the stat_smooth crosses y = 0.1.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using log10 trans that is (if not modified) undefined for negative values. Trans substitutes `fun` return values in  `stat_function()` with `log10(0.93389 + -0.25608 *x + 0.01663*x^2)`. You dont have negative `yvals` but you have negative fitted values for `0.93389 + -0.25608 *x + 0.01663*x^2`. See this sample:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = xvals, y = yvals))+
stat_smooth(method= 'lm', formula = y~poly(x,2), se = F, color = 'blue')+
  stat_function(fun=function(x) log10(0.93389 + -0.25608 *x + 0.01663*x^2), color = 'green')+
geom_point(color = 'blue', shape = 22, size = 3)+
geom_hline(yintercept = 0.1)+
geom_vline(xintercept = 4.675868)
```

[image]

If you replace `trans = 'log10'` with `trans = 'pseudo_log'` you get matching curves:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = xvals, y = yvals))+
stat_smooth(method= 'lm', formula = y~poly(x,2), se = F, color = 'blue')+
  stat_function(fun=function(x) 0.93389 + -0.25608 *x + 0.01663*x^2, color = 'green')+
geom_point(color = 'blue', shape = 22, size = 3)+
geom_hline(yintercept = 0.1)+
geom_vline(xintercept = 4.675868)+
scale_y_continuous(trans = 'pseudo_log')
```

[image]

**FURTHER DEVELOPMENT OF ANSWER**

Find my considerations in comments:

```
  # find coefficients of lm and rename them for easier readibility 
  cmdl <- lm(df, formula = yvals ~ I(xvals^2) + I(xvals)) %>% 
    coef() %>% 
    `names<-`(c("c","a", "b"))
    
  y <- 0.1 # your desired y value for which we are looking equation roots (x'es) 
  
  # as y = ax^2 + bx + c => ax^2 + bx + (c - y) = 0
  cmdl[['c']] <- cmdl[['c']] - y
  
  # solve quadratic equation (note: without any a == 0 check) and get two roots for the specific case
  x <- (-1*cmdl[['b']]+ c(1, -1) * sqrt(cmdl[['b']]^2 - 4 * cmdl[['a']] * cmdl[['c']])) / 
    (2*cmdl[['a']])
   
   # x values ==
   [1] 10.725647  4.675868

   # And plot the result
   ggplot(df, aes(x = xvals, y = yvals))+
   stat_smooth(method= 'lm', formula = y~poly(x,2), se = F, color = 'blue')+
   stat_function(fun=function(x) 0.93389 + -0.25608 *x + 0.01663*x^2, color = 'green')+
   geom_point(color = 'blue', shape = 22, size = 3)+
   geom_hline(yintercept = 0.1)+
   geom_vline(xintercept = 4.675868)+
     geom_vline(xintercept = x, color = "orange", lty = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. How do I now plot that with a log axis for y?

Comment: @Charlie And how do you suppose to represent scaled negative values? See the results of `c(1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0, -1)` and `log10(c(1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0, -1))` respectively

Comment: Hi. y can never be negative in the dataset. I just want a fitted curve to the data and to be able to give the value of x when y=0.1

Comment: @Charlie Find the edited answer with my explanation. One of the roots matches your vline

Comment: I think you have misunderstood. The vline is plotted using the result of the lm model so it matches your data fine because you have solved the quadratic to get the answer which is how that number originated. The problem is that the vline does not cross the stat_smooth when plotted with a log scale. I need to be able to produce a graph with a log axis, stat_smooth quadratic fits and say that when y=0.1, x=n. At the moment I cannot do that as when plotted on a log axis, when y=0.1, x is clearly higher than 4.68. I think what I am asking for is maybe not possible.